# Create Multiple Threads in certain time for Java

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

What is the best way to create 500.000 threads in 5 seconds. (Runnable) I created for loop but it takes lots of time. For example;

```
startTime = System.currentTimeMills();

for (int i=0;i<500.000; i++){
 // create thread
  thread.start();
}

resultTime = (System.currentTimeMills() - startTime);
```

So the resultTime is bigger than 5 seconds. I know it depends on my hardware and os configuration but i just want to know what is the best way to create multiple threads in certain time?

Thanks.

Comment: Mmm. Perhaps you could spawn lots of threads to do it ? :-)

Comment: Notice that your loop end condition is `i < 500.000`. 500.000 is interpreted as `double` in Java, this means that you are instantiating `500` threads, not `500000`. In any case 500k doesn't seem a reasonable amount of threads. Why would you need so many? I can't imagine how many context switches inside the JVM process this could lead.

Comment: Is it for testing liquid nitrogen on your overclocked processor?

Comment: Why would there be more context-changes/sec with 500000 threads than with 50?

Comment: Thanks for all reply. I am tring to develop load test scripts.

Answer (score 8):

I really can't imagine this is a good idea. Each thread takes a reasonable amount of resource (by default, 512k of heap for each thread) and so even if you create all your threads, your JVM will be fighting for resources.

If you have a requirement for 500,000 work units, I think you're better off creating these as `Runnable`s (and not all at once!) and passing them to a [ThreadPool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html) tuned to your environment.machine (e.g. a naive/simple tuning would be one thread per CPU)

Comment: It's not a good idea for deliverable code.  I assume it's some sort of test or research.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way to create many tasks is to use an ExecutorService

```
int processors = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(processors);

long start = System.nanoTime();
int tasks = 500 * 1000;
for (int i = 0; i < tasks; i++) {
    es.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // do something.
        }
    });
}
long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
System.out.printf("Took %.1f ms to create/submit %,d tasks%n", time / 1e6, tasks);
es.shutdown();
```

prints

```
Took 143.6 ms to create/submit 500,000 tasks
```

Comment: Not an answer to OP question.

Comment: The answer is; don't create hundreds of thousands of threads because a) your system will fall over b) its really inefficient c) you don't need to. Its the shere number of threads which is the problem, you only have 4-24 cores and they can only context switch so fast. How you create them doesn't matter.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Its pretty late to ask this but just went through this answer now and I have this question in mind! When you say `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(processors)`, won't it create only 4 fixed threads (assuming there are 4 processors) at any point of time?

Comment: @user1739812 Correct but you can give it 500K tasks and it will allocate those to the threads as efficiently as possible.

Comment: @user1739812 It is worth remembering that once all your CPUs are busy, adding more threads is likely to make the application slower, not faster as some assume.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can make a couple of special threads that generates 250000 threads each..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this one to expect your computer to smoke better:
concept: share the job among each core.

```
public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            new Thread(new ThreadCreator()).start();  // with 4 cores on your processor
        }
    }


}

class ThreadCreator implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 125000; i++) {
            new Thread().start();         // each core creating remaining thread
        }
    }
}
```

**Took only 0,6 ms** !!

Comment: Best so far. [no. of cores] thread-creating threads seems like it might do better.